# How to exclude the error "Cannot resolve symbol" in Android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, mapbox

I try to create a map using Mapbox and Android studio. I am using official tutorial for this but in spite of this I have the errors "Cannot resolve symbol Mapbox/MapView and so on". Below I wrote the code that I have used and picture.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.mapbox.maps.MapView;
import com.mapbox.maps.Style;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
       mapView?.getMapboxMap()?.loadStyleUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS);
   }
}
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAJJz.png)

Comment: Do you have mapbox dependency declared as per the docs? https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/

Comment: Don't post your credentials. The picture you posted shows correctly configured repo, do you have dependency declared as well?

Comment: Sorry but How to check whether dependency declared ? I have declared all dependency accrording to tutorial about installation  
 https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/    I hope that it's right